# How to query selector by value?

Tags: javascript

Several elements in a page have the `id=myid`. I want to find the element having the value text = "findme". But how?

```
<div id="myid">some</div>
<div id="myid">findme</div>

document.querySelectorAll("div[id='myid']"); //TODO how to match value=findme?
```

Only native JS, not jquery.

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski It's not a duplicate. I want to find the element explicit having the text value "findme". The code above returns already all elements having the certain id.

Comment: It is a duplicate. I've fixed the pointer to aim at the right question.

Comment: "Several elements in a page have the id=myid." — Don't do that. Write HTML instead.

Comment: @Quentin I know, but I'm not in control of the page

Comment: here is your answer @membersound  please visit https://jsfiddle.net/sunnysm/2ad75u9q/

Comment: In general you HTML is invalid if you are using IDs more than one time. A ID must be unique! Use validation services to check your HTML! If you want to mark many elements then us a class or a name to find all instances.